# Selenium получает пустую страницу Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Не могу понять из-за чего скрипт может сделать скрин главной страницы https://kaspi.kz/shop/, а вот скрин категории не может https://kaspi.kz/shop/c/ebooks/, получаю белый экран, скрипт запускаю на ubuntu.

Использую:
Ubuntu 18
Chrome и WebDriver версии 79.0.3945.36
Selenium 3.141.0

Если делать тесты на Windows, то все работает нормально.
Что я не учел в скрипте из-за чего получаю белый экран?

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="/opt/chromedriver-79.0.3945.36/chromedriver")
driver.set_window_size(1920, 2000)
driver.get("https://kaspi.kz/shop/")
time.sleep(2)
driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
print (driver.title)
print (driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему используя сторонний сервис для создания скриншотов http://pikwy.com/